# html_entity_decode() in xsl not decoding anything

Tags: php, xml, xslt

I am attempting to do the following

```
<div class="floatLeft">
    <xsl:attribute name="class"
                  >mainQuestionTextNoteBellowAsterisk floatLeft</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:copy-of 
         select="php:functionString(
                    'html_entity_decode',
                    questionbody/child::node()
                 )"/>
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
</div>
```

I have replaced `'html_entity_decode'` with other string modifiers and works as expected even encoding, but when I try to decode the string I get the exact same string. Is there something I am missing?  below is the call I am using to process the xml

```
$XSLTProc = new XSLTProcessor();
$XSLTProc->registerPHPFunctions();
$XSLTProc->importStyleSheet($xslDoc);
```

Any help is welcomed!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to solve this exact problem, how ever I just decoded the xml file before processing.